# How to properly define several types to one entity in typescript?

Tags: typescript

(code in the end)

I try to write `section.full.link` but it gives me such error:

> Property 'link' does not exist on type 'SectionSingle | SectionTitle | SectionHeaderMedia'.
> Property 'link' does not exist on type 'SectionSingle'.ts(2339)

I cant understand what should i do to avoid this error.
Sign `?` after`full` property or something doesn't help

Code:

```js
export type Section = {
    type: "single" | "double" | "title" | "headerMedia";
    full?: SectionSingle | SectionTitle | SectionHeaderMedia;
}


export type SectionSingle = {
    type: "text" | "media";
    content: any;
}

export type SectionTitle = {
    title: string;
}

export type SectionHeaderMedia = {
    link: string;
    alt: string;
}

var section: Section = {
    type: "headerMedia",
    full: {
        link: "/somelink",
        alt: "some alt text"
    }
}

const cond = section.type === "headerMedia" ? `${section.full.link}` : null

console.log(cond)
```

Comment: Please provide a self-contained [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing, *as plain text in the body of your post*. Ideally I could paste such code into a standalone IDE and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it. So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values. (If you want to provide a [playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WvK3kw) that's great, but please also put the full example *in the body of the post as text*.)

Comment: If section.full should have all three types together, you may want to use `SectionSingle & SectionTitle & SectionHeaderMedia`
In your case, `SectionSingle | SectionTitle | SectionHeaderMedia` means `section.full` is one of these three types. `SectionTitle` and `SectionSingle` don't have `link` property, that's why TypeScript is complaining

Comment: @FaridShabanov `|` stands here cuz it may be one of them, not all of them

Comment: @bluepuper please re-read my comment. I asked, several times, for the example code to be in plain text in the body of the post.  We cannot *require* that someone visit an external link in order to see the issue.  And your playground link is corrupt, so it doesn't even work.  Right now there is no code to look at.

Comment: @jcalz here we go. done

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need your original `Section` type to be a union, something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WyeLxW).  Does that meet your needs?  Note that you have quite a lot of code for this to be a [mre].  Does the question truly depend on the specifics of `SectionHalfDoubleMedias` etc?  Could you pare it down to the smallest amount of code that reproduces the issue?  I don't want us to get distracted by all the different possible ways `Section` could be in your actual code; instead we should be fixing the problem in a toy example and then you can use that fix in your actual code.

Comment: If my suggestion for making `Section` a union works, I'm happy to write up an answer.  If not, you might want to [edit] the code example to be more minimal and demonstrate what's still not working.

Comment: @jcalz error is gone) thanks! Also wants to check others solutions, just to get several ways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like your current definition of `Section` is too loose, as it allows a value of a type like `{type: "headerMedia", full: SectionSingle}`, where the `full` property and the `type` property do not agree with each other.  So you can't check `section.type === "headerMedia"` and conclude that `section.full` has a `link` property.

If you want to encode this constraint, you should make `Section` a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) type, where `type` is the *discriminant* property.  Here's one possibility (although I don't know the full extent of your requirements):

```
export type Section =
    { type: "single", full: SectionSingle } |
    { type: "title", full: SectionTitle } |
    { type: "headerMedia", full: SectionHeaderMedia };
```

So a `Section` is one of those three possibilities. If you check `type` and it is `"headerMedia"`, then the `full` property has to be a `SectionHeaderMedia`.  And thus your check will succeed as written with no error:

```
const cond = section.type === "headerMedia" ? `${section.full.link}` : null; // okay
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.7.4#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcDyAbAJgZWAYxgEsIA7OAXjgG8AoOBhZYALjgCIBnI0gcw2Ds4AHw5YIAVwBGAoaPbEYskRwAWwAIZZgUALLAsRDewDc9RgDMJGDAH42eQiVI4e-VKMfEyAFSJKPOC9nAAlNbT0DIzMAX1paUEhYJhQggm9yCnMGahTWDm4+WQAaOCsbB3TnVyLUGJFsmjy2BX8SsusMSqdfNrqGxiakFBb1LR19Q2NS8q60ntIw8cipuBizBPBoeGHUYLIa90oaRt2WmFAYOQ4AWyjjM0H8MgvSGDYNUkRY+MTtvPmGT8AWOdEGigEbE4MCgbh+mySO2YgNC4Qm91BjQwPAA1lCYXDGhoMO84NDYXx4QA3DRQMlVMjdDKY8HMUZolZGdjFRqzNhgwaMbGkPEcAD0nAgd2FOO5jUGxNJXClqEVCEu7EacTitGepGhcD1WGOnAZpAAdLtKBQqOwxhFJly4LY4AADAAk1FNC3Ns3NMpirrgbFInXieslAn9EF4AAojQBKIA)

Answer (score 1):

You have to create type guard `isSectionHeaderMedia`

```js
function isSectionHeaderMedia(section: unknown): section is SectionHeaderMedia {
    return _.isObject(section) && 'link' in section;
}
```

`_` means lodash here.

```js
isSectionHeaderMedia(section) && section.type === "headerMedia"
?
<div key={index} className="w-full">
    <Image
        src={section.full.link}
    />
</div>
:   null
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions)

```
const cond = section.type === "headerMedia"
  ? `${(section.full as SectionHeaderMedia).link}`
  : null
```

or if you want a runtime check, you can transform the `SectionHeaderMedia` type into a class, and add one more condition on the `if` using the `instanceof` operator

```
export class SectionHeaderMedia {
  link = '';
  alt = '';
}

section1.type === 'headerMedia' && section1.full instanceof SectionHeaderMedia
    ? section1.full.link
    : null;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can crate a `generic` Section that handles all the cases and generates proper `full` types.

Then you can create a union type of all the possible sections and then you can use it the way you want.

```
type HalfSection = {

}

type SectionSingleText = {

}

type SectionSingleMedia = {

}

type SectionTitle = {
    title: string;
}
type SectionHeaderMedia = {
    link: string;
    alt: string;
}

type SectionSingle = {
    type: "text" | "media"
    content: SectionSingleText | SectionSingleMedia
}

type SectionType = "single" | "double" | "title" | "headerMedia";

type SectionGeneric<ST extends SectionType> = {
    type: ST;
    full: ST extends "single" ? SectionSingle : ST extends "title" ? SectionTitle :  ST extends "headerMedia" ? SectionHeaderMedia : never;
    left?: HalfSection;
    right?: HalfSection;
}

type Section = SectionGeneric<"single"> | SectionGeneric<"double"> | SectionGeneric<"title"> | SectionGeneric<"headerMedia">

const a: Section = {
    type: "headerMedia",
    full: {
        link: "link",
        alt: "alt"
    }
};


const fToCall = (section: Section): void => {
    section.type === "headerMedia" && console.log(section.full.link)
}

fToCall(a)
```

Note:

1. I had to declare some types to make this work
2. You may just as well create a union type from the beginning.

Here's a [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=50&ssc=11&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAEghgGwGYGUIGNgEsD2A7KAXigG8AoMgXwtEijU1zxSzwHMEIAVCAD2CKkK1MrWgNs+Fu04BZCABMscQeSo1w4jJLxcswTqrJQTUbAYgAuKAGdgAJ1ZsA3OrH1tTGBDgKI9+SUVYnJTKARWAGtrO0d2VzDEYBiHJ1cRdwkmaQ5oEONTMWsAImA+YGKoAB8oYoBbRWVigpN0fDK8ZI9GKSdOHn5q7p0cuUa4dVFNYaYuaeJimz6ISprihRwAVwAjTlXa8z2h4oALHz8A8eLXKbos-ABxCDx-LHQAHhQuKHLnhRsZvg5pAAHxGMJFehcBKmJCbBAIaxfH78P4AxbLSoAfkBzGWUCR31+eH+B30Rxx9105Og1ihKI6pNO538gSaUEpnnw3l8rPGBKgLwAbv4YSZOEhgFjrPBkFSxVBHGwTlKZYhUFy8OkNHdNYIqU8Xo4PhiZCswTUDc9XiaNjs9hbcYabe9SjTio6rUa3q6zrzLkEPRQ2ng7FA4Ei9fkIZoSn6Lmy4MUADQtKBwhHWUJhUwRPDRWp5yIptOJBBdYpJZphaiUG5kENhpBcHAAYUQCEEAAobJrIz08ABKaxCnBYBREMHZky9gcAOnchCXtXjfMDUAAZBuoI2cJw5wgcGwe5q5xmEAeooPJs22x2u3BrxQgA).

You may also want to read up on [Discriminated Unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes-func.html#discriminated-unions).